# JavaFX: Render issues with SceneBuilder

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have a strange render issue with Scene Builder, but only if I imported the JAR from ControlsFX.

As you can see in the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dD1euLDKt0I

the controls on the right side are disappearing behind a white rectangle when I resize the Scene Builder to the right. It seems, that the hover effects, that are decleared in the css, cannot be applied.

Does anyone have an idea how this rendering issue can happen and why it is only when I import the ControlsFX JAR?

Answer (score 0):

It is a know [issue](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/16/rendering-problem-when-loading-a-fxml-with).

At Gluon's open source [repository](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder), you can have a look at the different [issues](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues?status=new&status=open) filed about Scene Builder.

Some of these issues are already being fixed. You can clone the repo and build your version. Or you can wait until the [next release](http://gluonhq.com/release-schedules-for-javafxports-and-scene-builder/) of binaries.

Comment: Yeah i know that the issue is present in the gloun issues, because im currently working on it to fix this.